# How to access and store input when new JTextFields are created

Tags: java

Im trying to create a GUI that mimics an organizer/scheduler but im having an issue when i insert more fields for the user to input their task. In my code i have a button specified for adding more fields and another to submit them, but if the user chooses to add more fields i can only access the current fields but not the previous ones when they enter submit. How can i access previous fields?

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;  

class Organizer extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
     protected JTextField dateText,taskText, priorityText;
     Button addField;
     Button submit;
     JPanel panel;
     Vector<String> Dates = new Vector();
     Vector<String> Tasks = new Vector();
     Vector<String> Priority = new Vector();


     public void createWindow()
     {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Organizer");
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

        addField = new Button("(+)");
        addField.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(addField);

        submit = new Button ("submit");
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(submit);

        addFields();
     }

     public void addFields()
     {
        dateText = new JTextField("Enter Date(mon/dd/yyyy)",30);
        taskText = new JTextField("Enter Task",30);
        priorityText = new JTextField("Rate importance(10-high,1-low)",30);

        panel.add(dateText);
        panel.add(taskText);
        panel.add(priorityText);
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
     {
        if(evt.getSource() == addField)
        { 
          addFields();
          panel.revalidate();
          panel.repaint(); 
        }

        if(evt.getSource() == submit)
        {
           String temp = dateText.getText(); 
           System.out.println(temp);

           //Dates.addElement(temp);
           //System.out.println(Dates);
        }
     }

     public static void main (String[] args)
     {
        Organizer Org = new Organizer();
        Org.createWindow();
     }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend adding them all to a list, then you can just loop through your list of new fields.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store group of `JTextFields` added to `JPanel` each time `addField` `JButton` is clicked to an `ArrayList`. And while submitting you could retrieve the same. Here is the rough demo of what you code should look like:

```
class FieldsGroup //Represents each group of JTextFields
{
    JTextField dateText;
    JTextField taskText;
    JTextField priorityText;
    public FieldsGroup(JTextField dateText,JTextField taskText,JTextField priorityText)
    {
        this.dateText = dateText;
        this.taskText = taskText;
        this.priorityText = priorityText;
    }
    public String getDateText()
    {
        return dateText.getText();
    }
    public String getTaskText()
    {
        return taskText.getText();
    }
    public String getPriorityText()
    {
        return priorityText.getText();
    }
}
```

Then within your `Organizer` class you should create an `ArrayList` object as follows:

```
     ArrayList<FieldsGroup> groups = new ArrayList<FieldsGroup>();//Create an ArrayList
```

Change the `addFields` method in following way:

```
     public void addFields()
     {
        dateText = new JTextField("Enter Date(mon/dd/yyyy)",30);
        taskText = new JTextField("Enter Task",30);
        priorityText = new JTextField("Rate importance(10-high,1-low)",30);

        panel.add(dateText);
        panel.add(taskText);
        panel.add(priorityText);
        groups.add(new FieldsGroup(dateText,taskText,priorityText));//add each group of JTextFields to ArrayList object groups.
     }
```

And finally change the `submit` button `actionPerformed` as follows:

```
        if(evt.getSource() == submit)
        {
            for (FieldsGroup gr : groups)
            {
                System.out.println(gr.getDateText());
                System.out.println(gr.getTaskText());
                System.out.println(gr.getPriorityText());
                System.out.println("-----------------------------");
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to extract a new panel-class containing the dateText,taskText, priorityText and keep a List around for the panels you added.